# Creating a Teams Webhook "unified groups aren't supported"?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Morning all... at a client, tried to add a webhook connector in Teams, and got "something went wrong, unified groups aren't supported". Web hits suggest the user needs an exchange license, but he already has that. Also checked https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/connect-apps-to-your-groups-in-outlook-ed0ce547-038f-4902-b9b3-9e518ae6fbab?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us and OrganizationConfig is set correctly to allow Connectors, and TeamsConnectors. Any ideas?

```
PS> $org = get-organizationconfig

PS> $org.ConnectorsEnabledForOutlook

True

PS> $org.ConnectorsEnabledForTeams

True

PS> $org.ConnectorsEnabledForTeamsLastUpdateTime

01 January 0001 00:00:00

PS> $org.ConnectorsActionableMessagesEnabled

True
```

Saw this post as well, but it wasn't helpful: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/adding-mailchimp-app-error-403-forbidden-unified/81566058-71dc-45e5-9e32-3eb9b7bfae85

Comment: Could please confirm which webhook you are trying (incoming or outgoing) and please share your Teams version and console logs.

Comment: @Ravindra-MSFT - was on 1.4.00.11161, but I upgraded him to 1.4.00.16575. Is using the Incoming Webhook. Console logs appear to have an awful lot of personally identifiable info in them, any way to easily sanitise?

Comment: Please look into this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook#:~:text=Incoming%20webhooks%20are%20special%20type%20of%20Connector%20in,want%20to%20POST%2C%20typically%20in%20a%20card%20format.) which may help you.

Comment: It doesn't - that just tells me how to add one. The issue is the error I'm getting, not that I don't know how to add a webhook. I've checked the portal. Incoming Webhook as an app is allowed.

Comment: Exactly the same thing happens in Teams web interface - so it's not client-related.

Comment: Strangely, this worked as our global admin in the web interface. That should not have been necessary however, as the account in question was a team owner.